# How do you get the values from a stored procedure in postgresql into a java application? I keep getting an error

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure in my postgres database with a simple SELECT statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT device FROM dev_op_test ORDER BY device;
```

In the java app I am trying to get the list of devices into the resultset:

```
// Get unique devices from table
String sql = " { ?= call sp_search_devices() }";
CallableStatement statement = pgConn.prepareCall(sql);
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
```

And I keep getting the following error:
[image]

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? The sp_search_devices() is not expecting any input parameters as it is just a pretty simple SELECT statement.

Comment: If you want to return a result, use a set returning function, not a procedure

Comment: Thank you. It did work the way you suggested. Coming from a SQL Server world to postgres is a little frustrating at times :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_search_test_ui_devices()
    RETURNS SETOF text AS $$

    SELECT DISTINCT device AS device FROM dev_op_test ORDER BY device;
    
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

and

```
String sql = " SELECT sp_search_test_ui_devices() ";
PreparedStatement statement = pgConn.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
```